# Killing (close) a Twitter Boostrap modal, already opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can i kill an already opened Bootstrap modal? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzjZM/) example:

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        $('#myModal').on('show', function() {
            if(true) { /* Kill (close) this modal on some condition */}
        });

    });
</script>
```

I've tried:

```
if(true) { $('#myModal').modal('hide');   } // Not working
if(true) { $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); } // Too much recursion!!! :P
if(true) { return;                        } // Nope
```

Comment: According to the bootstrap docs, `$('#myModal').modal('hide')` should definitely work. If not, we won't be able to help out without having some pasted code to look through...

Comment: @ChristianEngel jsFiddle created. Your example is not working by the way.

Comment: Clicking on the backdrop of the modal will close the modal. You could always fire a `.click` event. Don't actually do this. :)

Comment: @Marrowmaw i need to close the modal if `$.get()` fails, and show another modal with an error text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [as @ChristianEngel correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736892/30433), the JSFiddle you provided in your question is listening to the `show` event on a non-element (`#modal-delete`), whereas it should be attached to the actual modal (`#myModal`) [which you did correctly in your code].

Second, despite that correct observation, I can still attest that I am seeing the behavior that you are complaining about, and here's why: the **show** event is triggered before the actual modal has been shown, and hence your call to `hide()` is made before the rest of the `show()` code.  One way to fix it would be to listen to the `shown` event instead. **That is not the way to do it!!**

The correct way to do what you are attempting is to simply call `preventDefault()` on the event.

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function(e) {
  if (true) {e && e.preventDefault()}
});
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzjZM/3/)

This will save a whole bunch of unnecessary code being executed.

By the way, I'll just add that I think this scenario illustrates quite well the reason for having both a `show` and a `shown` event.  While not the only reason for the `show` event, having it trigger *before* the action occurs allows for the developer to cancel it when required.

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything works as expected.
I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nzjZM/1/

Comment: You could also simply add the attribute `data-dismiss="modal"` to every button in the action bar that should close the modal.

Comment: OK, maybe i can't explain very well. I need to close the modal if something happens (e.g. $.get() fails). Of course your link closes the modal...

Comment: So simply call `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` and the modal will fade away, as demonstrated in my fiddle...

Comment: You are not constrained to call that function in an click event. Just fire your ajax request and close the modal in the error callback.

Comment: You can't get the point. `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` does NOTHING inside `.on()` function. As demostrated in my fiddle... I edited the question, maybe you can get it better.

Comment: Yeah, because your event never get fired.
You are listening on the `show` event on your button, but you have to listen on your modal itself: `$('#myModal').on('show', ...);`